# Subversion Client for Windows Vista

Tags: windows, svn

Can someone recommend me, free if possible, subversion client for Vista?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is very good.

Comment: If you find you are having performance problems, you can disable caching in TortoiseSVN and that can improve machine performance.

Comment: Aye, is the way to go! +1

Comment: Only downside is that they release updates frequently, and they require machine reboots (it's exceptionally rare for me to reboot my Vista dev box, other than windows updates, tortoise updates, and the occasional BSoD).

Comment: Actually, I find that the reboots aren't really needed.  Particularly on the updates.

Comment: Just because there are frequent updates doesn't mean you have to apply them.  If there's nothing changed that you need, just skip it.  I much prefer frequent updates to glacial updates though.  Active projects are good.

Answer (score 6):

There is always the trusty command line version of svn.  I use this in addition to GUI versions, I have run into too many instances where the GUI version has a problem and I have to resort to the command line to fix it.

I have also used [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html) and been very happy with it.  It is more of a full fledged client, rather than an extension to the explorer.  This has some benefits, in that it will monitor and show you all your current changes and those pending changes.

Comment: Which windows cmdline version do you use? Can you recommend one that handles windows paths fine? (no cygwin stuff)

Answer (score 3):

SubClipse is great if you are using Eclipse.

Comment: update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Subversive (http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) is another Eclipse option.

Answer (score 3):

I really like [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) if you're using Visual Studio.  It's free for a 30 day trial, then $49.  Well worth the 50 bucks, in my opinion.

If you **have** to have free, and using Visual Studio, try [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).  I've used it before, and it works fine.

Comment: +1 for the VisualSVN client for Visual Studio.  Excellent product, even their *FREE* server product is awesome.

Comment: I've heard good things about AnkhSVN, but I couldn't get it working on my system.

Comment: @Brian: At the AnkhSVN support mailing list we don't have any open installation Issues. Can you tell us about your problem? (Not much we can do if we don't hear of our (possible) users :))

Answer (score 0):

[Subcommander](http://subcommander.tigris.org/) has been very helpful for me; it too is a full-on client as opposed to an Explorer extension. The GUI is a little non-inutitive at first, but it works great otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you look for, but the Subversion does include a client when you install it: the svn command. It is an excellent client when you get used to it. Combined with a merge tool for handling conflicts you have all the power from your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise is great. Having both is not a problem, and many environments, such as Netbeans, will take full advantage of the command line interface if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I use SlikSVN on Windows 7 (So I imagine it'd work fine on Vista). It's a command line client, and does exactly the same as the unix SVN. I also use TortoiseSVN for gui goodness - there's no reason you can't use both.